# jqgrid cannot see the search add, edit delete buttons

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

My first time using jqgrid, i am able to manually load the data in the grid, however i cannot see the search/add/edit/delete buttons please help.
here is the jsp code.

Also have the follwoing css and the js libraries

Thanks in advance.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css" />
<script src="javascript/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="javascript/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="javascript/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="javascript/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

">
    My JSP starting page

```
function mycheck(value) {

alert('here');
if(parseFloat(value) >= 200 && parseFloat(value)<=300) {
    return [true,"",""];
} else {
    return [false,"The value should be between 200 and 300!",""];
}
}
```

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

```
var mydata = [ {id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"}, 
            {id:"2",invdate:"2007-10-02",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"}, 
            {id:"3",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"}, 
            {id:"4",invdate:"2007-10-04",name:"test",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"}, 
            {id:"5",invdate:"2007-10-05",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"}, 
            {id:"6",invdate:"2007-09-06",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"}, 
            {id:"9",invdate:"2007-09-01",name:"test3",note:"note3",amount:"400.00",tax:"30.00",total:"430.00"} ]; 

   jQuery("#custv").jqGrid({ 
          url:'jqTest.do?query=dummy', 
          datatype: "local", 
                 colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'], 
                 colModel:[ {name:'id',index:'id', width:60, sorttype:"int"}, 
                                     {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90, sorttype:"date"}, 
                                     {name:'name',index:'name', width:100}, 
                                     {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"}, 
                                     {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"}, 
                                     {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right",sorttype:"float"}, 
                                     {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false} 
                              ], 
                       rowNum:10, 
                       rowList:[10,20,30], 
                       pager: '#pcustv', 
                       sortname: 'invdate', 
                       viewrecords: true, 
                       sortorder: "desc", 
                       caption:"Local Grid", 
                       editurl: "jqTest.do?query=dummy" 
   }); 

for(var i=0;i<=mydata.length;i++) 
    jQuery("#custv").jqGrid('addRowData',i+1,mydata[i]);
```

});

jQuery("#custv").jqGrid('navGrid','#pcustv' , {search:true, edit: false, add:false, del:false, searchtext:"Search"});
//jQuery("#list4").jqGrid('navGrid','#pcustv',{del:false},{reloadAfterSubmit:false},{reloadAfterSubmit:false});

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it's the same problem I did. You are correctly using a jquery css file. The button images that the grid uses come from the jquery theme as well. So the images files from the theme are expected to be in a subdirectory called Images in a directly under the directory containing the css file (in this case, in the css/Images directory)

Comment: this is the answer...  I put my images folder in the root so I had to change all the image/ to ../image/

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines inside the doc ready block:

```
jQuery("#custv").jqGrid('navGrid','#pcustv' , {search:true, edit: false, add:false, del:false, searchtext:"Search"}); //jQuery("#list4").jqGrid('navGrid','#pcustv',{del:false},{reloadAfterSubmit:false},{reloadAfterSubmit:false});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following piece of code to your jqgrid

```
$("#list").navGrid("#pager",
                //{view:true},
                {add:true,addtext:'Add',edit:true,edittext:'Edit',del:true,deltext:'Delete'},               
                {top:50,left:"100",width:500,url:'<?php echo $this->baseUrl() ?>/artist/edit',closeAfterEdit:'true'},
                {top:50,left:"100",width:500,url:'<?php echo $this->baseUrl() ?>/artist/add',closeAfterAdd:'true'},                                                         
                {url:'<?php echo $this->baseUrl() ?>/artist/delete',closeAfterAdd:'true'}
            );
```